# How to set up URL aliases for dynamically created URLs in DJANGO?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

In my site, I have pages that are created on the fly using primary keys (for privacy/security reasons using `uuid.uuid4()`) as the URLs. I end up with `.../reports/e657334b-75e2-48ce-8571-211251f1b341/` Is there a way to make aliases for all of these dynamically created sites to something like `.../reports/report/`.

Right now my urls.py includes the following:

```py
path("reports/<str:pk>/", views.report_detail, name="report")
```

I tried changing it to:

```py
re_path('reports/<str:pk>/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/reports/report/'), name="report"),
path("reports/report/", views.report_detail),
```

But I go to the site that has the links to the long URLs, I get the following error:

> NoReverseMatch at /reports/
> Reverse for 'report' with arguments '('e657334b-75e2-48ce-8571-211251f1b341',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reports/str:pk/']

The template for that site includes:

```html
<a class="card-title" href="{% url 'report' report.pk%}">
```

I also tried the following for urls:

```py
path("reports/report/", views.report_detail),
path('reports/<str:pk>/', RedirectView.as_view(url='reports/report/'), name="report"),
```

Which allowed the previous site to load, but when I clicked on the link got the following 404 error:

```html
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/reports/e657334b-75e2-48ce-8571-211251f1b341/reports/report/
```

I am trying to have one alias for multiple pages - essentially removing/replacing the long uuid with a single word.

Without trying to make an alias, the site works fine.

Comment: You should be using `path` not `re_path`, the url does not use a regex

Comment: @IainShelvington I did try path as well, but got a different error, I'll update the question to reflect.

Comment: You need to include a forward slash at the beginning of the url: `RedirectView.as_view(url='/reports/report/')` so that the redirect is absolute and not relative

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you, that fixed the 404 error. How do I then pass the variable?

Comment: The `pk`/`uuid`? Is there a reason why you do not want to include it in the url? Not even as a GET param?

Comment: @IainShelvington cleanliness mostly. I was hoping not have a 30 something long random string in the url

Comment: @IainShelvington if you mean ```path("reports/report/", views.report_detail, {"pk": "e657334b-75e2-48ce-8571-211251f1b341"}),``` how would I do that for multiple/dynamically created variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to pass the `pk`/`uuid` of the report to the shortened url, you could pass it in the session

Create a custom `RedirectView` that saves the `pk` to the session and then read that `pk` in the target view

```
class ReportRedirect(RedirectView):

    def get(self, request, pk):
        request.session['report_pk'] = pk
        return super().get(request, pk)


def report_detail(request):
    report_pk = request.session['report_pk']
    ...
```

You use the custom `RedirectView` just like the built-in one

```
path("reports/report/", views.report_detail),
path('reports/<str:pk>/', views.ReportRedirect.as_view(url='/reports/report/'), name="report"),
```